# Outlook: Any way to make folders that contain unread emails more obvious? (the folder tree in the panel on the left)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

Here's a screenshot of my folder tree in Thunderbird:

Thunderbird folder tree:

[image]

Using some CSS, I was able to make folders that contain unread messages very obvious.

Whereas in Outlook you can barely tell them apart, and they seem to be making this even worse rather than better lately? Apparently they used to be bold, then it was removed for no good reason.

Is there any way to make them more obvious in Outlook based of the existence of the "unread" flag? (or even anything else, such as "category" or "flagged status" etc)

In addition to the number of unread emails, can it also display the total number of emails (also shown down the right-hand-side of my Thunderbird screenshot)?

Comment: Is Outlook actually making those bold, but the bold difference isn't as obvious?  If so, you could try a different default font for Outlook that has a more obvious bolding.

Comment: @fixer1234 Microsoft removed the boldness in Outlook 2016 (or maybe earlier) - for no good reason, and it's annoyed many people.  

Unless you know of a way to get it back?  

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7f6c62a3-0222-4036-904c-58adcb8f1708/outlook-folders-no-longer-bold-when-having-unread-items?forum=Office2016ITPro  

https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/15694968-bold-folder-names-for-unread-mail

Comment: Bold folders names are displayed within outlook 2010 if there is any unread messages in the folder. However, this behavior has been changed since Outlook 2013. Now you have to distinguish whether there is any unread mails in the folder by the unread items counter displayed next to the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the folder tree provided "as-is" in Outlook. You can't customize it at all.

This is a strongly requested feature, so please [vote for it on Outlook UserVoice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/11573343-enable-colored-mailbox-folders-or-color-coded-all).